# Get SPUser by passing Email address

Tags: email, spuser

i have an Email address of particular user. Now i want the SP username of that particular email address programatically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
SPUtility.GetLoginNameFromEmail
```

can be used to get login name.

```
SPUtility.GetIdentifierFromEmail
```

can be used to get user id.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. but it has been deprecated & we can use SPUtility.ResolvePrincipal instaed.